# why S:String.indexOf(T:Substring) return <function1> in scala

Tags: scala

```
scala> var a = List("1","2","3")

a: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> a.foreach(_ => print((_:String).indexOf("123"))) 

< function1> < function1> < function1>
```

Comment: Why tags for java and js?

Comment: Is there anything you expected it to be?

Answer (score 2):

```
 a.foreach(_ => print((_:String).indexOf("123")))
```

... is not the same thing as ...

```
 a.foreach(x => print((x:String).indexOf("123")))
```

For one thing, the underscore, `_`, represents a passed parameter only once. If you encounter something like `_ + _` it does not mean the parameter is added to itself, it represents the addition of two different passed parameters.

So what is `(_:String).indexOf("123")`? It is an anonymous function that takes one parameter of type `String` and attempts to find the index where the sub-string "123" can be found. In this case the underscore is unrelated to the parameter sent to the `foreach` lambda.